# Google Maps v3 - marker custom icon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change the icons of the markers on the map, but when I show more than 20 springs a black shadow to the icon.

Javascript:

```
for (var i in markers) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng),
        map: map,
        icon: 'icons/google/employe-male-red.png',
        draggable: false
    });

    marker.markerId = markers[i].markerId;
    marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: markers[i].infoWindows
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your marker icons have glow. So if many markers are in same place, it makes glow less transparent.

Lose glow or group markers with [markerclusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer).